# How to convert datatype of numbers from string to integer in python

Tags: python-3.x

I generated a hash value for a file in python. The value consists of both characters and numbers. If i check the data type of each value, it is showing as string for both letters and numbers. How do I convert the data type of numbers from string to int?

Thanks in Advance!

```
    import hashlib
    myl = []
    fobj = open('akash.txt','r')
    buffer = fobj.read()
    hsh = hashlib.sha512()
    hsh.update(buffer.encode('utf-8'))
    val = hsh.hexdigest()
    for i in val:
             print(type(i))
    fobj.close()
```

The hash value generated by the code is:

> cf83e1357eefb8bdf1542850d66d8007d620e4050b5715dc83f4a921d36ce9ce47d0d13c5d85f2b0ff8318d2877eec2f63b931bd47417a81a538327af927da3e

I expect the output to be as

```
    <class 'str'>
    <class 'str'>
    <class 'int'>
    ...
```

But this is the output Im getting

```
    <class 'str'>
    <class 'str'>
    <class 'str'>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I truly have no idea why you would want to do this, but you can try if you can convert a character in the hash string to an integer first and then print the type. Just change your loop as follows

```
for i in val:

    try:
        n = int(i)

    except ValueError:
        n = i

    print(f'character: {n} is {type(n)}')
```

Comment: Or just `for i in val: print(i, i.isnumeric())`